# Trouble solving uninitialised value error given by Valgrind

Tags: c, debugging, valgrind

I'm currently writing a test program that parses input from a stream. I won't go into too much detail about this program but I am currently trying to parse alphanumeric characters and then assign them to a temp string, **temp[100]**. After all valid characters are assigned to **temp**, I allocate memory and **strncpy** to the allocated string variable.

Valgrind complains about my two usages of **strlen** and my single use of **strncpy**. Why is this? It complains about an uninitialised value but I made it clear that it won't do any allocation unless there are characters inside **temp**. Any suggestions?

```
char *name(char a)
{
    int x;
    char c;
    char *returnName = 0;
    char temp[100];
    int i = 0;

    /* Ensures no character is skipped */
    temp[i] = a;
    i++;

    /* Fill temp one character at a time */
    while((x = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        c = (char)x;

        /* Valid characters are assigned */
        if((isalnum(c)) || c == '_')
        {
            temp[i] = c;
            i++;
        }

        /* As soon as invalid character appears, exit loop */
        else
            break;
    }

    /* Make sure temp is not NULL before mallocing */
    if(temp[0] != '\0') /* Thank you Alter Mann for this fix */
    {
        printf("Before malloc\n");
        returnName = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(temp)+1);
        printf("After malloc before strncpy\n");
        strncpy(returnName, temp, strlen(temp)+1);
        printf("After strncpy before return\n");
        return returnName;
    }

    /* If nothing is assigned, return NULL */
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: You never null-terminate your string in `temp`.

Comment: Wow. I cannot believe I forgot about that. I will do that right now and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never null-terminated your string in `temp`, so both `strlen()` and `strcpy()` are reading past the initialized values in your array, hence the uninitialized value errors Valgrind is giving you.

Change:

```
char temp[100];
```

to:

```
char temp[100] = {0};
```

and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
if(temp != NULL)
```

You need to check

```
if(temp[0] != '\0')
```

`temp` is an array, not a pointer.

And (as pointed out by Paul Griffiths), NUL-terminate your string after the `while` loop:

```
temp[i] = '\0';
```

Comment: I understand that now and I will keep that in mind. Paul Griffiths answer solved my problem but I know your suggestion has saved me a few more headaches. Thank you!